# include environment file in another environment chef file

Tags: chef-infra

We have multi environments in my team, each one has its own environment file.
Currently we have to copy-paste the file, and update all the files ones some shared resource is used.

Is there a way to include env file in env file - like doing import in python/ include in c++

So we can do a basic env file and include it in all other env files
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can combine environment files, if you use Ruby files (and not JSON). `eval` allows you to execute any code, which could be read from just another file.

I'm not using that in production, yet, but this is what I have currently stashed:

```rb
# environments/production.rb

name "production"

env_cookbook_versions = {
  "mysql" => "<= 6.0.18",
}

env_default_attributes = {}

# include the defaults here    
eval File.read("global_settings.rb")
```

The settings shared among multiple environments (and respecting the parametrization used in the specialized files) could be as follows:

```rb
# environments/global_settings.rb

env_cookbook_versions["apache"] = "= 1.0.0"
cookbook_versions(env_cookbook_versions)

env_default_attributes.merge!({
  "whatever" => "foo"
})
default_attributes(env_default_attributes)
```

EDIT: You would then use `knife environment from file`to upload all the environments that include the `global_settings.rb` file. As soon as these common settings change, you have to upload all dependent environments again, as all logic happens only on your workstation.

Comment: Thanks, i will have to re write the environment file, but i think it will be worth the work.

Comment: I did this steps:  
`knife environment from file environments/global_settings.rb`  
`knife environment from file environments/testing_env.rb`  
`knife bootstrap -E testing_env --run-list "role[bla_bla]" --sudo <machine id> -x ubuntu`  

what i see is that the chef does not recognise the other file changes.  
Any ideas?

Comment: I've extended my answer a bit. Not sure, what you mean. If you change `global_settings`, you have to re-upload all dependent environments.